# LaPlace transform of the delta function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having difficulty taking the laplace transform of $$\delta(t-2\pi)\cos(t)$$ I know that if we have the delta function it is just $e^{-cs}$ but what about the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the delta function has the special property that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - a) f(t) dt = f(a)$$

(or more particularly, $\int_0^{\infty} \delta(t - a) f(t) dt = f(a)$ whenever $a > 0$) together with the definition of the Laplace transform. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok so I know this isn't part of the question but I am trying to solve $$y^{''}+y=\delta(t-2\pi)\cos t$$ and that is exactly what I did only to arrive at $y=2\sin t$ With initial conditions $y(0)=0\;\;y^{'}(0)=1$ which is not the answer. And I used that definition

Comment: @adam That's not the correct solution; the solution should somewhere involve a step function. What do you find for the Laplace transform?

Comment: I'm not sure but I get, $\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$ which is just $2\sin t$ right?

Comment: @adam After computing the integral involving the delta function, you should find that $$s^2 Y(s) - 1 + Y(s) = e^{-2\pi s} \cos{2\pi}.$$

Comment: but I just followed the definition you told me

Comment: @adam Following the definition, the appropriate $f$ is $e^{-st} \cos t$: Evaluating this at $t = 2\pi$ due to the delta function gives the result in my comment.

Comment: ahhh okok I forgot about the factor of $e^-st$. Could you technically use a convolution integral for this problem?

Comment: We would have to convolve $\dfrac{1}{s^2+1}$ with $\delta(t-2\pi)\cos t$ would this be possible to arrive at the same result?

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this:

$$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \delta(x-a) f(x) dx = f(a). $$

(Assuming $f$ is sufficiently nice.) Here your $f$ is given by $(e^{-s})^t\cos(t)H(t)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. Does this help?